# How to implement video calls in Android?

Tags: android

I want to implement video call functionality in my application. I didn't found any resource on the internet like any SDK, API which I can use to make the video call.

What things can I start to research?

Comment: minimally you will have to have a central server to connect to so if one phone is on wifi an has a private NAT'd IP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for "video call" in Android at this time, sorry.

Comment: How can you say this, skype is supporting video calling.How they are doing it?

Comment: @Akanksha: They wrote their own.

Comment: Here is also sip API provided by Android for this.Any ways if you have any knowledge about how skype works, so please. Skype API is also available for this.but developers have problem in implementation.If we   use skpye API so is it require skype install in mobile.any third part dependency ?

Answer (score 1):

As eb4890 says in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410323/initiating-video-call/8024626#8024626), you can make a Video Call by using GTalk with this code:

```
Uri imUri = new Uri.Builder().scheme("xmpp").authority("gtalk").query("call;type=video").appendPath(email).build();
Intent IM = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
IM.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
IM.setData(imUri);
startActivity(IM);
```

Answer (score 0):

Video calling is easily possible if both the users have a 3G connection. I did a sample code where on a button click the call is initiated to a number.  I wrote  the following code inside the onclick listener:

```
      Intent callIntent = new Intent("com.android.phone.videocall");
            callIntent.putExtra("videocall", true);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phonenumber));
            startActivity(callIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The open source SightCall solution offers a strong SDK for Android.

You can access their documentation at http://docs.sightcall.com

Answer (score -1):

There are many platforms available for video calling. You can try [this](https://github.com/3bytessolutions/CallService-sample). It's very easy to use and no charges.