# Start video chat without user interaction - Android

Tags: java, android, button, keyevent, videochat

I am a total noob on this site so please be patient. I am trying to initiate a Video Chat/Call without any user interaction or confirmation.

I found this:

```
Uri imUri = new Uri.Builder().scheme("xmpp").authority("gtalk").query("call;type=video").appendPath(email).build();
Intent IM = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
IM.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
IM.setData(imUri);
startActivity(IM);
```

from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8024626/1184256

This gets me very close, but I then have to click an "Invite" button to continue. Is there a way I can emulate a KeyEvent to click this button or skip the popup window entirely with root access?

I don't even necessarily need to use Google Video Chat if someone has found a different way to initiate a Video call to a certain contact via Skype, Vtok,Fringe, ooVoo or whatever without user interaction.

I have also found [OpenTok](http://www.tokbox.com/) which after building a sample server and client on my site I have found that it works on desktop browsers but not in Android browsers. Please don't steal/use my apiKey or sessionId.

I have also found [libjingle](http://code.google.com/apis/talk/libjingle/index.html) which will allow me to use Google Talk's peer-to-peer voice and video chat. I am thinking this will be the way to go, but it means building a video chat app from the ground up and wrapping it around these libraries... yeah. Anybody done this already?

I know this is essentially a duplicate thread, but I have searched for days and days for an answer and this is the closest I have come to getting this done.

BTW the reason I need this without user interaction is for a Telepresence robot, thus there won't be anybody actually holding/using the phone when I initiate this call.

Please HELP!

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to actually change the built in android app (Talk?) that receives this intent to automatically accept these types of intents.  There's no way to do it from a standalone app for security reasons.

Comment: I also think this is correct - but is there any manual entry stating this for a fact?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that live video streaming will work natively in Android Browsers, since they dont support WebRTC (Yet) and do not support flash. With that said, OpenTok has an [Android SDK](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk) in beta that lets you stream live video from android phone to browser, another android phone, or even an iOS phone as long as everyone is connected to the same session. Like you said, this does not work over the browser and you would have to build a native app.

Comment: opentok has a 30 day trial. it's not completely free