# Android: Activate video call from my app

Tags: android, video, videochat

i'm trying to make a video call from one mobile to another mobile through my app. For this i followed different approaches available in online, like

1. [java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Chat_Video/Download_Free_code_Sample_Video_Chat_android.htm) i included all files as they suggested in the description (Above the download header) but they forgot to include OnCameraViewListener file. So, i'm not able to run this project (For my code please see this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2zgf01fb9ryitan/VideoChat.rar?dl=0))
2. I fallowed [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8024626/3142611), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10139108/3142611) and many but nothing was helpful for me.

So, any one please help me to make a video call from android app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to make a video call from my app but it's not able to achieve at this time so i used skype for this

Code:

```
Intent skypeVideo = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
skypeVideo.setData(Uri.parse("skype:" + "endUserSkypeId" + "?call&video=true"));
context.startActivity(skypeVideo);
```